# Stripe webhooks to monitor whether customer has an active payment method

Tags: stripe-payments

Customers on my site use the Stripe Billing portal on user sign up to enter a payment method (card or ACH). What webhook can I use to monitor whether they have at least one active payment method?

I know I can use customer.source.created when a payment method is created and customer.source.deleted when a source is deleted. However a user can initially create two methods and delete one but still have an active method. I just need to know whether they have at least one available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you receive `customer.source.created` OR `customer.source.deleted` events, you typically receive `card` object as the payload. Since the [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/object#card_object-customer) property on the `card` object is expandable, you may not see it included by default on the `card` object.

In which case, you'd likely need to retrieve the `card` object again by calling the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/retrieve) and expanding `customer` property on it. Once you get the customer ID, you can call this [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list) to list customer's payment methods. This should allow you to see if they have any other PaymentMethods or not.